# How to keep the first minute of a batch of videos without reencoding with FFMPEG?

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

I have ~90 videos that I'd like to keep only the first minute of. I've seen answers that do this for individual videos, but not batches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution

```
for %%a in ("*.*") do ffmpeg -t 60 -i "%%a" -acodec copy "newfiles\%%~na.avi"
```

Comment: Remove `-ss 1`. That seeks from 1st second.